# adminhtml fields dependency

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, adminform, system.xml

I'm learning the Magento form generation feature and I have an question related to `system.xml` file. Here's the code example:

```
    <days translate="label">
      <label>Days</label>
      <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
      <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_locale_weekdays</source_model>
      <sort_order>10</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
      <comment>Days</comment>
    </days>
    <sunday translate="label">
      <label>Sunday</label>
      <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
      <source_model>xxx_xxx_Model_System_Config_Source_Hours</source_model>
      <sort_order>100</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
      <comment>Hours in Sunday</comment>
      <depends>
        <days>0</days>
      </depends>
    </sunday>
    <monday translate="label">
      <label>Monday</label>
      <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
      <source_model>xxx_xxx_Model_System_Config_Source_Hours</source_model>
      <sort_order>110</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
      <comment>Hours in Monday</comment>
      <depends>
        <days>1</days>
      </depends>
    </monday>
```

The source model returns list of hours - from 0 to 23.

Why when I select Sunday and Monday only Sunday dependency appears, but when I select only Monday, the Monday dependency appears as it should, but how to get working multiple dependences with multiselect field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why when I select Sunday and Monday only Sunday dependency appears,
>   but when I select only Monday, the Monday dependency appears as it
>   should

In PrototypeJS/JavaScript, `$('multiselect').value` will always return, in order of appearance, the first selected option only. This first selected option is then compared with the value given as dependecy:

- Sunday + Monday = Sunday
- Monday = Monday
- Monday + Tuesday + Wednesday = Monday

> how to get working multiple dependences with multiselect field?

The only solution I can think of is replacing [the original JavaScript function](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.2/js/mage/adminhtml/form.js#L530) that is used to handle dependencies. Currently, it cannot determine multiple selected values.